# how to call methods from another class with lower case?

Tags: flutter, dart

how to call methods from another class with lower case?

For example, there is a class like this:

```
class Zip{
  List<ZipData> keys = [...];
  String encrypt({String stringForEncrypt}) {
    String string = stringForEncrypt;
    keys.asMap().forEach((index, value) {
      string = _zip(string: string, index: index);
    });
    return string;
  }


  String _zip({String string, int index}) {...}
}
```

I call the given method like this:

```
String str = Zip().encrypt(stringForEncrypt: "lorem ipsum");
```

but I would like to call this method inside other classes like:

```
String str = zip.encrypt(stringForEncrypt:"lorem ipsum");
```

How can I do it?

Comment: You can use `Zip zip = Zip()` as a global variable.

Comment: I mean like `json.encode ();` or `jsonEncode ();`

Comment: make `encrypt()` static and name the class as `zip`    `class zip{static String encrypt({String stringForEncrypt}){}}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you would like to call your method like this

```dart
String str = zip.encrypt(stringForEncrypt:"lorem ipsum");
```

Then you can declare a variable that will store the `Zip` class, like so

```dart
final Zip zip = Zip();
```

Then you will be able to access your methods and variables from the variable `zip` that you just declared.

If you would like to access your methods and variables like this

```dart
String str = Zip.encrypt(stringForEncrypt:"lorem ipsum");
```

Then you need to make your method `static` within your `Zip` class.

```dart
class Zip {
   static encrypt(...){
       //do something
   }
}
```